# how to pipe a loop to one socat connection

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd, netcat, socat

```
for /l %x in (1,1,5) do  echo hello | socat - TCP:localhost:700
```

When I use socat manually, I can send and recieve multiple lines in one socat instance. However, it seems that I can only send one line in bash, which doesn't seem right. How can I send multiple lines, one at a time, to socat?  ,The for loop runs once and closes.   I am using windows

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: `(for /L %x in (1,1,5) do echo hello) | socat …`